# Flutter Getx : type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'RxDouble'

Tags: flutter, types, arguments, double, flutter-getx

I am using `Getx` package on my flutter app. I want to update a double value. but it's show me an error.

*here is my gextController*

```
class CustomWebViewCTRL extends GetxController {
 
  RxDouble progress = 0.0.obs;

  onProgress(pro) {
    progress = (pro / 100);
  }
}
```

And then I am trying to call it on my home screen by `Obx(()=>)` and `GetBuilder` also. No one works for me. It's saying -

*"The argument type 'RxDouble' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double?'"*

Here is a sample (where I want to use) :

```
GetBuilder<CustomWebViewCTRL>(builder: (controller) {
            return LinearProgressIndicator(
              value: controller.progress,
              color: Colors.black,
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
            );
          }),
```

How can I fixed this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When assigning values to Rx Types use-value property.try with this

```
 progress.value = (pro / 100);
```

Comment: thanks I again mistake it.